# What is Teshuvah?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah

I’m trying to understand what Teshuvah is, is it repenting and ceasing evil or also restitution?

I ask because restitution is not always possible

Comment: Related (one of many) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90534/the-rambams-complete-repentence-halachical-logistics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Alter Rebbe in Tanya [(Igeret Hateshuva, chapter 1)](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/1029221/jewish/Chapter-1.htm), Teshuva means:

> to return to G‑d with all his heart and soul, to serve Him, and to keep all His commandments.

Teshuva means confessing the sin you did, and saying to yourself "I am not doing it again". This is why the Rambam [says](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911891/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Two.htm) that when is Teshuva done succesful? When a person encounters the exact same situation in which he sinned earlier, but this time, he can abstain:

> A person who confronts the same situation in which he sinned when he has the potential to commit [the sin again], and, nevertheless, abstains and does not commit it because of his Teshuvah alone and not because of fear or a lack of strength.

The Rambam also asks,
וּמַה הִיא הַתְּשׁוּבָה, what is teshuvah? He [answers](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911891/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Two.htm):

> That a sinner should abandon his sins and remove them from his thoughts, resolving in his heart, never to commit them again as [Isaiah 55:7] states "May the wicked abandon his ways...." Similarly, he must regret the past as [Jeremiah 31:18] states: "After I returned, I regretted."
>
> [He must reach the level where] He who knows the hidden will testify
> concerning him that he will never return to this sin again as [Hoshea
> 14:4] states: "We will no longer say to the work of our hands: `You
> are our gods.'"
>
> He must verbally confess and state these matters which he resolved in
> his heart.

So, what is Teshuvah?

1. Teshuvah is to return to G-d with all your heart and soul;
2. Teshuvah is verbally confessing to G-d what sin you did;
3. Teshuvah is abandoning the sins; leave them behind; do better;
4. Teshuvah is, after you abandoned the sins, resolving in your heart never to commit the sin ever again.

How do you know if this succeeded? Well, G-d gives us trials. Why? Because G-d wants us to build on ourselves. To make ourselves better. If we sinned in a particulair area, G-d will send a test in that area. If we succeed to abstain from sinning, great. Teshuvah was done succesfully. If not, that is a sign that you'll need to work a bit harder.

The Torah in Devarim 30:11 says:

> For this commandment which I command thee this day, it is not hidden from thee, neither is it far off.

The Ramban, Nachmanides, [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.30.11?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) that "this commandment" in this posuk specifically refers to teshuvah:

> And it was said indirectly to hint at the promise because it will be this way in the future. And the reason to say this is because if your wanderers be in the edges of the heaven and you are in the hands of the nations you will be able to return to G-d and to do all I [G-d] command to you today. Because this thing is not  too esoteric or distant for you, but rather is very close to you to do it in every time and in every place. And this is the meaning of "in your mouth and in your heart to do it": **That they should confess their sins and the sins of their ancestors with their mouths and return in their hearts to G-d** and welcome onto themselves today the Torah to do it the generations as it is mentioned (Deuteronomy 30:2) "you and your children with all of your heart" as I have explained there.

Comment: Excellent response.

Comment: Who convicts a person of sin so that teshuvah can come true? Is there anything on the part of God that has such a role as Christians attribute to the Holy Spirit? Or is this something entirely down to the person's individual strength?

Comment: Thank you sir, great answer

Comment: @Thales I'm not familiar with the Christian approach to this, but it is probably best thinking about it in terms of a relationship between a person and God.  Sin damages the relationship and Teshuva is the process of repairing it in much the same way that human relationships work.  Eg. if a husband shouts at his wife and then he follows a similar process of feeling bad about shouting, apologising, stopping shouting at her and resolving not to again in future, this would be the equivalent of sin and Teshuva.  No one "convicts" him of sin - it is about the damage and repair to the relationship.

Comment: @Thales G-d. G-d does give a person the chance to do teshuva. He brings a certain situation so that the person will be able to overcome it. Have a great Shabbos!

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. no problem. Glad to be of help. If you find this answer helpful, please consider marking it "checked". Great Shabbos!

Comment: @Shmuel great answer as always, although I'm not sure it deals with the restitution point thoroughly enough

Comment: @RabbiKaii Sorry, but what exactly does restitution mean in this case?

Comment: @Shmuel it's unclear so I was assuming the most general case. For example how can a thief do teshuva from stealing from someone he can no longer find?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that when we do something improper we should not pray but decide not to do it again, and develop good habits that help assure that we will not repeat the mistake. Rambam said that when people make a mistake they should resolve not to repeat it. You have to change your behavior.

I think this is in his Guide, and if not, it is in his Mishneh Torah.

Comment: Rambam also says clearly that in addition to changing your behavior you must verbally confess.

Comment: "we should not pray" - this part is incorrect. Part of teshuvah, maybe the main part, is rebuilding the relationship with G-d that he damaged with his sin. Part of rebuilding that relationship is confessing, apologizing, and asking for forgiveness. _In addition_, he should insure that he won't do it again; that will be included in his apology.

Comment: @MichoelR It is good to say prayers verbally, however, words are meaningless without action. You have to change your behavior.

Comment: @Shmuel They are not mutually exclusive; the Rambam lists both as requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Shmuel's take, one can view "teshuvah" as a return to the self Hashem created you to be.

R YB Soloveitchik points out that the Maimonides gives this perspective. Laws of Rependence 2:4 reads (tr. R Elihyahu Tauger, emphasis mine):

> מִדַּרְכֵי הַתְּשׁוּבָה לִהְיוֹת הַשָּׁב צוֹעֵק תָּמִיד לִפְנֵי הַשֵּׁם בִּבְכִי וּבְתַחֲנוּנִים וְעוֹשֶׂה צְדָקָה כְּפִי כֹּחוֹ וּמִתְרַחֵק הַרְבֵּה מִן הַדָּבָר שֶׁחָטָא בּוֹ וּמְשַׁנֶּה שְׁמוֹ **כְּלוֹמַר אֲנִי אַחֵר וְאֵינִי אוֹתוֹ הָאִישׁ שֶׁעָשָׂה אוֹתָן הַמַּעֲשִׂים** וּמְשַׁנֶּה מַעֲשָׂיו כֻּלָּן לְטוֹבָה וּלְדֶרֶךְ יְשָׁרָה וְגוֹלֶה מִמְּקוֹמוֹ. שֶׁגָּלוּת מְכַפֶּרֶת עָוֹן מִפְּנֵי שֶׁגּוֹרֶמֶת לוֹ לְהִכָּנַע וְלִהְיוֹת עָנָו וּשְׁפַל רוּחַ:

> Among the paths of repentance is for the penitent to
> (a) constantly call out before God, crying and entreating;
> (b) to perform charity according to his potential;
> (c) to separate himself far from the object of his sin;
> (d) to change his name, **as if to say "I am a different person and not the same one who sinned;"**
> (e) to change his behavior in its entirety to the good and the path of righteousness; and
> (f) to travel in exile from his home. Exile atones for sin because it causes a person to be submissive, humble, and meek of spirit.

(If we sort out the Rambam's internal work from the practical steps he tells the penitent to take to get there, one has the four steps Shemu'el listed.)

The relationship between returning to G-d and returning to your true self is complicated. I hope it is obvious that they aren't entirely different things. But different perspectives on the same goal will lead to different priorities and strategies to get there , so I thought it was worth adding this to the conversation.